# How to split a column based on values in it?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `column1` value
" Test/ Elegant Conditions : TASK100: Elegant Item\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N "

I need to split `column1` into 2 columns and the output should be

column1 should do a left trim till : Test/ Elegant Conditions

column2 should do a left trim from : TASK100: Elegant Item and before first \

expected output.

```
Column2                    |  Column3                            
------------------------     ----------------------------            
Test/ Elegant Conditions      TASK100: Elegant Item
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
    [Description] [varchar](250) NULL
)

insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW08: Equipment Integrity\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW01: Task Planning/ Preparation/ Manning\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW03: Work Procedures - Availability and Suitability\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : TW17: Ventilation\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions : IT10: Hazard Recognition/ Perception\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions : IT06: Procedural Compliance\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions : HF01: Complacency/ Motivation/ Attitude\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Task/ Environmental Conditions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');

insert into [Test] values ('Organisational Factors : OS06: Design\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');  


insert into [Test] values ('Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N');
```

Comment: What have you tried? Charindex not good?

Comment: While the criteria for Column3 is to get data till `\` but end point for Column2 is vague? Please can you update your question for adding more details for capturing Column2 data. Also add more sample data and what have you tried upto now.

Comment: @dhruvjoshi   expected value for Column 3 is   **TASK100: Elegant Item**   before  first back slash (\)

Comment: What would you want your output to be for the value `Individual/ Team Actions\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the base string functions here:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    SUBSTRING(column1, 1, CHARINDEX(':', column1) - 1) AS column2,
    SUBSTRING(column1,
              CHARINDEX(':', column1) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('\', column1) - CHARINDEX(':', column1) - 1) AS column3
FROM yourTable
WHERE column1 LIKE '%:%\%';
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
declare @a varchar(300)

select @a = 'Test/ Elegant Conditions : TASK100: Elegant Item\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N '

select  @a C1,
        ltrim(rtrim(left(@a, charindex(':', @a)-1))) C2,
        ltrim(rtrim(substring(@a, charindex(':', @a)+1, charindex('\', @a)-(charindex(':', @a)+1) ))) C3
```

### Output

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|                                    C1                                     |            C2            |          C3           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| Test/ Elegant Conditions : TASK100: Elegant Item\|2018.04.11 00:01:37\|N  | Test/ Elegant Conditions | TASK100: Elegant Item |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Iam getting error " Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: You need to add more sample data to your question then, you obviously have some data that does not conform with the single example you have provided.

Comment: @MJH Add a `WHERE` clause which asserts that the data matches the pattern you attempt to parse.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: I could do that, but it's still unclear to me what the OP is trying to achieve as they have only supplied one piece of sample data.